# If a regular language only contains Kleene star, then is it possible that it comes from the concatenation of two non-regular languages?

Tags: concatenation, theory, regular-language, kleene-star

I want to know that given a regular language L that only contains Kleene star operator (e.g (ab)*), is it possible that L can be generated by the concatenation of two non-regular languages? I try to prove that L can be only generated by the concatenation of two regular languages.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know what theorems may be useful here. I'm trying to find a counter-example now.

Comment: You should ask this question on the new Computer Science Stack Exchange: http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement is false. Consider these two languages over Σ = {a}:

> L<sub>1</sub> = { a<sup>n</sup> | n is a power of two } ∪ { ε }
>
> L<sub>2</sub> = { a<sup>n</sup> | n is *not* a power of two } ∪ { ε }

Neither of these languages are regular (the first one can be proven to be nonregular by using the Myhill-Nerode theorem, and the second is closely related to the complement of L<sub>1</sub> and can also be proven to be nonregular.

However, I'm going to claim that L<sub>1</sub>L<sub>2</sub> = a*. First, note that any string in the concatenation L<sub>1</sub>L<sub>2</sub> has the form a<sup>n</sup> and therefore is an element of a*. Next, take any string in a*; let it be a<sup>n</sup>. If n is a power of two, then it can be formed as the concatenation of a<sup>n</sup> from L<sub>1</sub> and ε from L<sub>2</sub>. Otherwise, n isn't a power of two, and it can be formed as the concatenation of ε from L<sub>1</sub> and a<sup>n</sup> from L<sub>2</sub>. Therefore, L<sub>1</sub>L<sub>2</sub> = a*, so the theorem you're trying to prove is false.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! The counter-example you given is very elegant and correct. I love it very much.